Anti-commuting unbounded operators with the same domains of definition
Given two anti-commuting diagonalisable densely defined operators on a separable Hilbert space, when will their domains of definition coincide?
(Re)-Edit: (some clarification as requested) Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and left $D_1$ and $D_2$ be two densely defined operators on a common domain $V \subseteq H$. Assume that $H$ admits two orthonormal bases, one of which is an eigenbasis for $D_1$, and the other an eigenbasis for $D_2$, such the linear (uncompleted) span of each of the bases is $V$.  (By an eigenbasis I mean that each element of the orthonormal basis is an eigenvalue for the operator.) Moreover, assume that $D_1$ and $D_2$ anti-commute, that is to say $D_1D_2 = - D_2D_1$, on $V$. If $D_1$ and $D_2$ are both closable, then what can we say about the domains of their closures?

What precisely do you mean by anti-commuting and diagonalisable in this context?

@RobertIsrael: I have tried to clarify the situation. I hope it is clearer now.

If $v$ is an eigenvector of $D_1$ for eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $ D_2 v$ is an eigenvector of $D_1$ for eigenvalue $-\lambda$. Let's assume for simplicity that all eigenvalues are simple.  So if $e_\lambda$ is a unit eigenvector of $D_1$ for $\lambda$ and $e_{-\lambda}$ a unit eigenvector for $-\lambda$, we have
$D_2 e_\lambda = c_\lambda e_{-\lambda}$ and $D_2 e_{-\lambda} = c_{-\lambda} e_\lambda$ for some scalars $c_\lambda$ and $c_{-\lambda}$. Let $ c_{\lambda} = \mu^2 c_{-\lambda}$.  Then
$D_2 (e_{-\lambda} + \mu e_{\lambda}) = c_{-\lambda} e_{\lambda} + \mu c_\lambda e_{-\lambda} = \mu c_\lambda (e_{-\lambda} + \mu e_{\lambda})$, i.e. $e_{-\lambda} + \mu e_{\lambda}$ is an eigenvector of $D_2$ for eigenvalue
$\mu c_{\lambda}$, and similarly $e_{-\lambda} - \mu e_{\lambda}$ is an eigenvector of $D_2$ for eigenvalue $-\mu c_{\lambda}$.
But if you're insisting on eigenvectors for distinct eigenvalues being orthogonal, the only way $e_{-\lambda} + \mu e_\lambda$ and $e_{-\lambda} - \mu e_\lambda$ can be orthogonal with $e_{-\lambda}$ and $e_\lambda$ orthogonal is
$|\mu|^2 = 1$.  Thus $|\mu| = 1$, i.e. $|c_{\lambda}| = |c_{-\lambda}|$.
As for the common domain, that can be $V$. Having the same domain would only be a problem if you want these to be closed operators.
[EDIT] The domain of the closure of $D_1$ would be the set of sums
$\sum_\lambda x_\lambda e_\lambda$ such that  $\sum_\lambda (1+|\lambda|^2) |x_\lambda^2| < \infty$.  Similarly for $D_2$ with $1 + |\lambda|^2$ replaced by $1 + |c_\lambda|^2$.  If you want these domains to be the same, you'll want there to be bounds  $$0 < A < \frac{1+|\lambda|^2}{1 + |c_\lambda|^2} < B $$

Yes,  I want to consider the closure of the restriction of $D_1$ and $D_2$ to $V$. I will edit the question to make this clearer.
